# How to notate orchestral toms?

Tags: notation, percussion

I want to ask how are orchestral toms notated.

I Know how toms in a drumset are placed in the staff and there are only few of them but what if I want to use more toms with different pitches?

How to notate them?
Can I just arbitrarily place them on the staff based on their pitch or is there a standard way of placing the notes?

Comment: Are these toms with a drum kit, or are they just a set of toms? Are they tuned to definite pitches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not even a 'standard' way in which to show each drum! There are some 'industry standards', but the best to do in this case is to include a legend (key) at the top of the chart, explaining which line/space represents each tom. As it's a rare occurrence, that would be the safest to do.

If they're *tuned* toms, it could be an idea to signify their placing on the appropriate line/space.